# The + noun of + noun pattern

Tags: nouns, articles

I am wondering whether there is a rule concerning **"The + noun of (the) + noun"**. I mean, is there any rule specifying when to use **the** or **a/an** and when not? Here are some examples representing my concern, which among these are correct? I know that there have been some threads on this topis on the forum, but none of them answered my question.

1. The lack of the computer system.
2. Lack of the computer system.
3. The lack of computer system.
4. The view of the canal.
5. View of the canal.
6. The view of canal.

I hope I expressed my question clearly enough.

Comment: There is no "rule" relevant to your question as posed. It's syntactically impossible to dispense with the article before ***view of the canal*** (for any non-contrived context I can think of). But other such "noun phrases", such as ***lack of equipment*** can often be used with or without an article, according to personal preference. In short, it all depends ***which specific pair of nouns*** (and sometimes also the specific intended meaning and other aspects of "context").

Comment: If no computer system exists, it would be 'the lack of a'. If an organisation's system is down, we might possibly speak of 'the lack of the computer system'.

Comment: If there is no single rule for article usage -- and there isn't -- there can't be any single rule for a construction containing articles. Better to think about articles as peculiar to each noun phrase, as it is uttered, in context. Because that's the way native speakers treat them. They take context for granted, and when their presuppositions are violated they get as confused as you do.